# How can I prevent PyTorch from making little changes to my assigned values

Tags: python, floating-point, pytorch, precision, rounding-error

PyTorch makes little changes to my assigned values, which causes really different results in my neural network. E.g.:

```
a = [234678.5462495405945]
b = torch.tensor(a)
print(b.item())
```

The output is:

```
234678.546875
```

The little change PyTorch made to my variable `a` caused an entirely different result in my neural network. My neural network is a very sensitive one. How can I prevent PyTorch from making little changes to assigned values?

Comment: PyTorch by default uses single-precision floating point (nowadays called binary32). Python by default uses double-precision floating point (nowadays called binary64). If you want, you can specify the data type, but then your entire network will have to be converted to binary64. I suspect that's not your real problem, though. Why would your network be _that_ sensitive and not be considered overfitted?

Comment: Your value got changed before Pytorch even touched it.  Try printing out `a` immediately after the line where you assigned it, and you will see that it isn't exactly the value you gave.  Floats simply do not represent exact values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question is pretty broad; you haven't shown us your network. That means none of us can address the real issue. But the code sample you show has a more limited scope: why is PyTorch changing my floats?

PyTorch by default uses single-precision floating point (nowadays called binary32). Python by default uses double-precision floating point (nowadays called binary64). When you convert from a Python float to a PyTorch FloatTensor, you lose precision. (This is called *rounding*.)

If you want, you can specify the data type, but then your entire network will have to be converted to binary64.

Just for your example:

```
import torch
a = 234678.5462495405945
b = torch.tensor(a, dtype=torch.float64)
print(b.item())
# 234678.54624954058
```

---

If your network is that sensitive, you probably have bigger problems. You're likely vastly overfitted, or you're too focused on one training example. A lot of work on quantizing networks and showing performance curves as you use lower-precision numbers has been done.

Comment: How do I specify the data, I just don't want pytorch to change the values.

Comment: Edited the post to give an example.

Comment: if u intialize your tensor with float64 everytime,,it will not change the value,,  (note->)but will increase your model size